# Why does CMake ignore compiler directives

Tags: compiler-construction, cmake, cross-compiling

Why is CMake using /usr/bin/cc (c++) and not the compiler I give in the command?

```
bengt@bengt-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src/libftdi1-1.0$ cd build
bengt@bengt-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src/libftdi1-1.0/build$ sudo rm -R *
[sudo] password for bengt: 
bengt@bengt-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src/libftdi1-1.0/build$ sudo cmake -DMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7 -DMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7 ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1    
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
```

The compiler exists:

```
bengt@bengt-VirtualBox:/usr/local/src/libftdi1-1.0/build$ /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7 -dumpversion
4.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting

```
MAKE_C_COMPILER
```

You need to set

```
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
```

Similar for the CXX compiler. Use

```
$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7 \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.7 ..
```